# typeorm generic repository error when extending BaseEntity

Tags: typescript, repository, typeorm

I have an issue in typescript when creating a generic repo.
I want to enforce typing by enforcing the TEntity generic type to extend BaseEntity as follows :

```
@EntityRepository()
export class ClsGEntitiesRepository<TEntity extends BaseEntity> {
    private _dbConnection: Connection;
    private _entity: TEntity;

    constructor(entity: TEntity,  dbConnection: Connection) {
        this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
        this._entity = entity;
    }
```

However, when trying to use the getRepository, typescript is complaining when passing the Entity as the parameter of this function

**error : Type 'BaseEntity' is not assignable to type 'string | Function | (new () => TEntity) | EntitySchema'.**

```
const rootQuery = this._dbConnection
            .getRepository<TEntity>(this._entity)  <--error 
            .createQueryBuilder()
```

This is quite annoying, as I need to pass a string, which represents the name of the Entity (which is a class) as a workaround.

The weird thing is that if I use this method in a non generic class, it works fine. As you can see below the entity "TestEntity" is extending BaseEntity and I can use it in the getRepo with no issue

```
@Entity({
    name: "testentity",
})
export class TestEntity extends BaseEntity implements ITestEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: "uuid",
        nullable: false,
    })
    resourceId: string;
    @Column({
        type: "float",
        nullable: true,
        default: 0.0,
    })
    value: number;
}


    const a = dbConnection
    .getRepository<TestEntity>(TestEntity) <--no error
    .createQueryBuilder()
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using ObjectType when defining the entity in parameter:

```
@EntityRepository()
export class ClsGEntitiesRepository<
    TEntity extends BaseEntity
> extends Repository<TEntity> {
    private _dbConnection: Connection;
    private _entityName: string;
    private _entity: ObjectType<TEntity>; <--this fixed the issue

    constructor(entity: ObjectType<TEntity>, dbConnection: Connection) {
        super();
        this._dbConnection = dbConnection;
        this._entity = entity;
        this._entityName = this._dbConnection.getMetadata(this._entity).name;
    }
}

//example of usage
const TestEntityRepository = new ClsGEntitiesRepository<TestEntity>(
        TestEntity,
        getConnection()
    );
```

However now I have another problem, with types.
I have created an Entity implementing an interface.
BUT, I can not straight save an object of this interface in the entity, I have to cast it first and then can insert it.

I do not understand why TypeScript is complaining as the entity is implementing the interface.

To reproduce the error:

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

interface ITest {
    id: string;
    val: number;
}

@Entity({
    name: "theentity",
})
class TheEntity extends BaseEntity implements ITest {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: "character varying",
        nullable: false,
        default: "def",
    })
    id: string;

    @Column({
        type: "bigint",
        nullable: true,
    })
    val: number;
}

const record: ITest = {
        id: "id1",
        val: 2,
    };

const records: ITest[] = [record];

// TheEntity.save(records); <--complains

TheEntity.save(records as TheEntity[]); <--not complains and inserting fine in the table
```